# How can I view data exported from AWS RDS Performance Insights locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-rds, analysis

We use Performance Insights in RDS to discover and troubleshoot DB query issues. It is very useful to be able to look at a timeline with the dev team and point out the effect of badly formed queries being introduced to an environment. However we are on the free tier and only have this ability for one week before the data expires.

I am able to export Performance Insights data and save it to my local machine using the AWS CLI as described on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.API.html#USER_PerfInsights.API.Examples), e.g. to download DB Load stats grouped by Waits, I can do:

```
aws pi get-resource-metrics --service-type RDS --identifier db-Id --start-time 2023-02-15T12:00:00Z --end-time 2023-02-15T13:00:00Z --period-in-seconds 60 --no-cli-pager --metric-queries '[{"Metric": "db.load.avg","GroupBy": { "Group": "db.wait_event", "Limit": 7 }}]' > db-load-top-waits.json
```

However once I have this data locally I don't know how to view it except to step through it line by line. I have used tools like [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/) to view trends in dashboards that it creates from locally stored web app logs in standard formats. Is there anything similar that I can use against the JSON files I get from AWS?

Comment: You can convert it with to CSV with a tool like `jq` and display it in Excel. In general: you can convert it by anything and display in everything. Json is one of the most universal existing file formats. E.g. import it to Elasticsearch https://stackoverflow.com/q/15936616/1873862 and display in Kibana.

Comment: My bad, I shouldn't have said I "don't know how to view it" – obviously there are a ton of ways to view JSON data. My reference to GoAccess was in hope of hearing about a similarly purpose-built tool because I want to avoid building the graphs myself if I can.